# Adding table of contents to word Doc from excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Im attempting to manipulate word form excel, I am having a hard time establishing a word range within excel. Then once i establish that range i would like to insert a table of contents into that range.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Dim wordApp As Object
Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName:=templateLocation, ReadOnly:=False)

Dim TOCRange As Word.Range                'establishing my word range
Set TOCRange = wDoc.Paragraphs(3).Range
    TOCRange.SetRange Start:=TOCRange.Start, End:=wDoc.Paragraphs(3).Range.End

'inserting the table of contents ERROR

wDoc.tableOfContents.Add Range:=TOCRange, RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
 UseHeadingStyles:=True, IncludePageNumbers:=True, UseHyperlinks:=False, _
 HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:=False
```

This results in me getting a runtime error '438'
-"Object doesn't support this property or method.

I can use this macro fine when calling the word macro from excel, but i cannot seem to identify the document object in this case. This needs to be done from entirely form excel as my template documents cannot have any vba code in them.

Any information or resources about this topic would be greatly appreciated. Trying to get better everyday!

Comment: [`TablesOfContents.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.tablesofcontents.add), right? I think you're missing an `s`.

Comment: wow thank you so much. I cannot believe i have been spelling this wrong the whole time hahahahahaha. you are a legend.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish between a document and a template in Word. This is jargon. In Word, a template is a very specific kind of file. You do not generally open templates but rather add documents based on a template using the Documents.Add method. Here is a reference to that method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.add?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158072846)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396

I do have a question in that regard. Why not simply put a TOC field in your template to start with rather than use code to add it?

I played a bit with your code to just create a TOC in a new document which I then save as Deleteme.docx. I hope this helps. This requires a reference to the Word object model.

```vb
    Sub AddTOC()
        Dim wordApp As Word.Application
        Dim TOCRange As Word.Range                'establishing my word range
        Dim wdoc As Word.Document
        '
        Set wordApp = GetObject(Class:="Word.Application")
        'Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
        Set wdoc = wordApp.Documents.Add 'Open(Filename:=templateLocation, ReadOnly:=False)
        Set TOCRange = wdoc.Range
        TOCRange.Paragraphs.Add
        TOCRange.Paragraphs.Add
        TOCRange.Paragraphs.Add
        Set TOCRange = wdoc.Paragraphs(3).Range
        wdoc.TablesOfContents.Add Range:=TOCRange ' This does the same as your code
        wdoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="Deleteme.docx"
        wdoc.Close
        Set TOCRange = nothing
        Set wdoc = nothing
        Set wordApp = nothing
    '    Debug.Print wdoc.Name
    '    Set TOCRange = wdoc.Paragraphs(3).Range
    '        TOCRange.SetRange Start:=TOCRange.Start, End:=wdoc.Paragraphs(3).Range.End
    '
    '    'inserting the table of contents ERROR
    '
    '    wdoc.tableOfContents.Add Range:=TOCRange, RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
    '     UseHeadingStyles:=True, IncludePageNumbers:=True, UseHyperlinks:=False, _
    '     HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:=False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and the sample code. To answer your question, Im placing the table of contents in after i have generated the form because i have images and information being placed under certain tag names and such. When executing my find and replace macro, it grabs the tag names that are in the table of contents and places all associated information into the table of contents. This leaves the intended homes for the info blank with a lot of mess to clean up afterwards. current approach grabs tagName range and places TOC in that range. dont know how to do that yet tho, hopefully soon! Thanks

Comment: Things go into a TOC based on the styles being used, outline levels, or TC fields. The one in your original code is based on heading levels. It will do nothing with tags. You may want to look at Suzanne Barnhill's explanation of the nuts and bolts of how a TOC is constructed in that field. --- http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm